# How can I ensure the audio is playing at the same points in P5?

Tags: p5.js

I have just finished a project and discovered a problem that I did not even think was possible. I made a program that uses the amplitudes from a song and then takes those amplitudes and does whatever with it. The **critical** problem I discovered is that the timestamps vary in a significant way for each play-through of a song.

So, for instance, here are portions of two separate iterations of the same song.

Trial 1

```
  { vol: 1.0409142767327505e-19, timestamp: '0.16' },
  { vol: 1.0409142767327505e-19, timestamp: '0.17' },
  { vol: 5.2045713836637524e-20, timestamp: '0.19' },
  { vol: 5.2045713836637524e-20, timestamp: '0.21' },
  { vol: 5.2045713836637524e-20, timestamp: '0.22' },
```

Trial 2

```
 { vol: 0.000014893942946020693, timestamp: '0.15' },
  { vol: 0.000007446971473010347, timestamp: '0.17' },
  { vol: 0.000007446971473010347, timestamp: '0.18' },
  { vol: 0.000007446971473010347, timestamp: '0.20' },
  { vol: 0.0000037234857365051734, timestamp: '0.21' },
  { vol: 0.0000037234857365051734, timestamp: '0.23' },
```

See the difference? Not only do the timestamps not load up, but the volumes are different also, even when the timestamps do line up. This is very frustrating because I've worked very hard on this hackathon project and seems like its going to fall apart because of something that I couldn't have expected. If anyone knows something that might fix this, please let me know. I've tried smoothing the audio quality.

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]? How large is the difference? Notice that the volume in the first trial is in a different format than the volume in the second trial. Also my guess is that the timestamp values are not exact, so trial one might be `0.210` and trial two might be `0.219` or something like that. Is this really causing a problem?